# Exibir resultados de uma busca na mesma View AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-services

Eu estou desenvolvendo um app para poder estudar e, estava montando tudo no controller, todas as consultas e tudo mais. Só que depois resolvi passar tudo para um service(vi que é o correto fazer assim), só que quando passei as consultas para um service a minha busca simplesmente parou de funcionar.

No template eu listo todas as categorias cadastradas e nele tem um input, que faz a busca de todos estabelecimentos cadastrados no DB. Gostaria que quando o usuário fizer uma busca, a lista simplesmente atualize com uma nova, só que listando os resultados dessa busca.

Quando tento fazer uma busca, aparece o seguinte erro:

`Object {message: "sqlite3_bind_null failure: bind or column index out of range", code: 0}`

E assim está todo o código relacionado a esse template e a busca:

**Service.js**

```js
.service('Market', function($cordovaSQLite, DBA) {
  var self = this;
  
  // Listando todas as categorias
  self.allCategories = function() {
    return DBA.query("SELECT id, category_name FROM tblCategories")
      .then(function(result){
        return DBA.getAll(result);
    });
  }
  
  // Buscar por estabelecimentos
  self.searchPlace = function(nameSearch) {
    var parameters = [nameSearch];
    
    return DBA.query("SELECT id, place_name FROM tblPlaces WHERE place_name LIKE '%(?)%'", parameters)
      .then(function(result) {
        return DBA.getAll(result);
    });
  }
  
  return self;
})
```

**Controller.js**

```js
app.controller('CategoriesCtrl', function($scope, Market) {
  $scope.categories = [];
  $scope.categories = null;
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.items = null;
  
  var nameSearch = '';
  $scope.searchkey = '';

  // Função de clique onde pega o resultado do input e faz a busca
  $scope.myClick = function (search) {
    nameSearch = search;
    console.log(nameSearch);
    
    $scope.searchResult = function(nameSearch) {
      Market.searchAll(nameSearch).then(function(items) {
        $scope.items = items;
        console.log(items);
      });
    }
    
    $scope.searchResult();
  };
  
  $scope.listAllCategories = function() {
    Market.allCategories().then(function(categories) {
      $scope.categories = categories;
    });
  }
  
  $scope.listAllCategories();
})
```

**Categories.html**

```html
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
  <label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="key" autocorrect="off" ng-model="searchkey">
  </label>
  <button class="button" ng-click="myClick(searchkey)">Buscar</button>
</div>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="category in categories">{{category.category_name}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está chamando o .then no controller e no service, tente alterar o service para apenas isto:

```
self.allCategories = function() {
   return DBA.query("SELECT id, category_name FROM tblCategories");
};
```